# Godot freezes without any obvious errors on build

Tags: game-engine, godot

I've recently worked on a project in godot (**3.4 mono**).
During the process of developing the game I encountered the bug that the godot engine freezes during the build of my project (Has worked fine until then).

**What I've tried:**

- I thought that it would be an error in any  of my scripts so I went to debug my recent script -> Freezing happens before the script is launched because the debugger won't start.
- So I went to my other scripts and wanted to debugger those -> Same result.
- Next step: Created an empty scene -> same result.
- Next step: Created a new project and encountered the same behaviour..
- Final step: Downloaded a fresh godot version and got the same behaviour in a new project.

If someone encountered a similar problem or knows a point where to start it would help me a lot!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: with the help of Theraot I found the log files!:**

```
[Godot Log]
https://pastebin.com/7r9XJ7Rx
```

Comment: What operating system are you on? If you are on Windows, look in %appdata%, there should be a Godot folder, inside a mono folder, and you can find logs there. You can also go to the app_userdata folder and find logs per project. Also check in Editor Settings -> Mono -> Builds -> Build Tool, there should be an option for MSBuild and an option for dotnet CLI, whichever it has, try the other. Addendum: something else you can try is to download Godot 3.3.4 and see if it also presents the problem. If none of that works and nothing give you logs, you might have to make a debug build from source.

Comment: Thank you! I founf the log files and addet it to my Post after i did not find any nugs or errors in it.. Maybe you could breifly skim it if you can spot odd behavior?

Comment: It appears to have loaded the project assembly correctly. Do you also encounter problems with the non-mono version of Godot? What comes to mind is that you could have multiple GPUs (e.g. one integrated one added in expansion slot) and Godot is launching the game in an incompatible one (that usually means the integrated one). Some reports of problems in Windows 11 also come to mind, in particular that changing the default terminal can cause Godot to crash. Try, if you can, to find out what are the latest version of Godot that work. However, ultimately, I'd have to say open an issue on Github.